# Number of displayed posts

Tags: posts, get-posts

I have tried many things to solve this problem.

So I have a plugin which displays projects assigned to users in a widget. It displays projects as posts. The problem is that it only displays `5` projects on the page.

I am sending a code which display posts:

```
$projects = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'projects'));
```

One guy told me to change it to

```
$projects = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'projects', 'number posts' => 10));
```

which should help but it didnt.

Anyone have idea how to solve it ? I can send whole code if it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress function `get_posts()` supports:

```
'posts_per_page'  => 10,
'numberposts'     => 10,
```

so you should use:

```
$projects = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'projects', 'numberposts' => 10));
```

instead of

```
$projects = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'projects', 'number posts' => 10));
```

If you want to show all posts, you can use

```
'posts_per_page'  => -1
```

You can read more about this in the WordPress Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Damn one space made a difference.. MAny thanks for help, its working perfect !:)

Thanks and best regards,
Arek K.

Comment: That happens to the best of us ;-)